# Is it a good idea to define partial copy with operator= (assignment)?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Please consider the following snippet:

```
class Pin
{
public:
    Pin()
    {
    }
};

class Connection
{
    Pin& _from;
    Pin& _to;

public:
    Connection(Pin& from, Pin& to)
        : _from(from), _to(to)
    {
    }
};

class Device
{
    Pin _a, _b;
    Connection _int_conn;

public:
    Device()
        : _int_conn(_a, _b)
    {
    }
};
```

Now I'd like to define `operator=` so that `Device` can be copied one to another:

```
int main()
{
    Device a, b;

    a = b;
}
```

Of course, the default `operator=` doesn't suffice because the `Connection` class holds two references. For this particular operation, it is however desirable that the `Device` copies all other properties and leaves the references intact (since they are expected to always point to the 'parent' pins).

On the other hand, the `Connection` class can be also used by user, and then the two pins can belong to any other class. In this case, although copying other properties may be beneficial, it seems a bit incorrect to use `operator=` for that. In other words:

```
int main()
{
    Pin a, b, c, d;
    Connection y(a, b), z(c, d);

    y = z;
}
```

to copy non-reference members seems wrong to me.

Moreover, if I ever decided to change references to pointers, I'd probably want `operator=` to copy them as well.

Am I right here? What is the best course of action? I think about defining an additional method like:

```
void Connection::copy_properties(Connection& rhs)
```

or just copying them in `Device::operator=`.

Comment: Why do you use references then? Looks like what you need is pointers, so you can freely manipulate them. References, unlike pointers, cannot be changed once initialized.

Comment: As I pointed out, I *may* change them to pointers at some point. But that's not the point, I believe. I tend to do one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [the references] are expected to always point to the 'parent' pins.

Is this an invariant of `Connection` or of `Device`? If the latter, consider this version of `Connection`:

```
class Connection
{
    Pin* _from;
    Pin* _to;

public:
    Connection(Pin& from, Pin& to)
        : _from(&from), _to(&to)
    {}
};
```

That is to say, this version has somewhat more obvious copy semantics. Then `Device::operator=` now has to make sure to not break the `Device` invariant (e.g. assign whatever needs assigning while leaving `_int_conn` unchanged). And in fact making `_int_conn` a `const` member can enforce that; but that's only as useful as the `const` interface of `Connection`.

Comment: This is an invariant of `Device`. As the text states later, `Connection` can basically use any pins. And wouldn't making `_int_conn` a `const` mean that I won't be actually able to modify any of the other members *I wanted to copy*?

Comment: @MichałGórny The qualifier only affects `_int_conn`. I feel like you should amend your question -- "it is however desirable that the `Device` copies all other properties" make it sound like you're talking about the members of `Device`, not `Connection`. It is not usual for a class to take care of copying the members of another class on its behalf.

Comment: Yes, I guess it isn't usual — that's why I was thinking of a method clearly copying the mutable members.

Comment: @MichałGórny An alternative is to provide a member to retarget, i.e. that only sets `_from` and `_to`. The `Device` can then properly retarget to its pins after assignment.

Comment: Hmm, you are probably right that if `Device` requires that property from its connections, it should probably ensure that...